# joblib connection to Dask backend: tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, dask-distributed, joblib, dask-ml

I am running a simple program on my dask worker. Below is the program.

```
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client


import joblib
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC

client = Client('127.0.0.1:30006', timeout=10000)
client.get_versions(check=True)
import pandas as pd
digits = load_digits()

param_space = {
    'C': np.logspace(-6, 6, 13),
    'gamma': np.logspace(-8, 8, 17),
    'tol': np.logspace(-4, -1, 4),
    'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
}

model = SVC(kernel='rbf')
search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_space, cv=3, n_iter=50, verbose=10)


with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'): #Running it on dask worker
    search.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
```

30006 is my port on which scheduler is running.

I am getting the below error.

```
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop object at 0x000001DC4E701850>>, <Task finished name='Task-42' coro=<DaskDistributedBackend.apply_async.<locals>.f() done, defined at C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\_dask.py:316> exception=CommClosedError('in <closed TCP>: Stream is closed')>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 187, in read
    n_frames = await stream.read_bytes(8)
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 741, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 765, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\_dask.py", line 317, in f
    batch, tasks = await self._to_func_args(func)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\_dask.py", line 306, in _to_func_args
    await maybe_to_futures(kwargs.values())))
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\_dask.py", line 289, in maybe_to_futures
    [f] = await self.client.scatter(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 2084, in _scatter
    await self.scheduler.scatter(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 852, in send_recv_from_rpc
    result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 635, in send_recv
    response = await comm.read(deserializers=deserializers)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 202, in read
    convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 126, in convert_stream_closed_error
    raise CommClosedError("in %s: %s" % (obj, exc)) from exc
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <closed TCP>: Stream is closed
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop object at 0x000001DC4E701850>>, <Task finished name='Task-44' coro=<DaskDistributedBackend.apply_async.<locals>.f() done, defined at C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\_dask.py:316> exception=CommClosedError('in <closed TCP>: Stream is closed')>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\code\condavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 187, in read
    n_frames = await stream.read_bytes(8)
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
```

Below  is my package information:

```
{
    "scheduler": {
        "host": {
            "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
            "python-bits": 64,
            "OS": "Linux",
            "OS-release": "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2",
            "machine": "x86_64",
            "processor": "",
            "byteorder": "little",
            "LC_ALL": "C.UTF-8",
            "LANG": "C.UTF-8"
        },
        "packages": {
            "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
            "dask": "2021.01.0",
            "distributed": "2021.01.0",
            "msgpack": "1.0.0",
            "cloudpickle": "1.6.0",
            "tornado": "6.1",
            "toolz": "0.11.1",
            "numpy": "1.18.1",
            "lz4": "3.1.1",
            "blosc": "1.9.2"
        }
    },
    "workers": {
        "tcp://10.1.1.92:37435": {
            "host": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "python-bits": 64,
                "OS": "Linux",
                "OS-release": "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2",
                "machine": "x86_64",
                "processor": "",
                "byteorder": "little",
                "LC_ALL": "C.UTF-8",
                "LANG": "C.UTF-8"
            },
            "packages": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "dask": "2021.01.0",
                "distributed": "2021.01.0",
                "msgpack": "1.0.0",
                "cloudpickle": "1.6.0",
                "tornado": "6.1",
                "toolz": "0.11.1",
                "numpy": "1.18.1",
                "lz4": "3.1.1",
                "blosc": "1.9.2"
            }
        },
        "tcp://10.1.1.93:45855": {
            "host": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "python-bits": 64,
                "OS": "Linux",
                "OS-release": "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2",
                "machine": "x86_64",
                "processor": "",
                "byteorder": "little",
                "LC_ALL": "C.UTF-8",
                "LANG": "C.UTF-8"
            },
            "packages": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "dask": "2021.01.0",
                "distributed": "2021.01.0",
                "msgpack": "1.0.0",
                "cloudpickle": "1.6.0",
                "tornado": "6.1",
                "toolz": "0.11.1",
                "numpy": "1.18.1",
                "lz4": "3.1.1",
                "blosc": "1.9.2"
            }
        },
        "tcp://10.1.1.94:36523": {
            "host": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "python-bits": 64,
                "OS": "Linux",
                "OS-release": "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2",
                "machine": "x86_64",
                "processor": "",
                "byteorder": "little",
                "LC_ALL": "C.UTF-8",
                "LANG": "C.UTF-8"
            },
            "packages": {
                "python": "3.8.0.final.0",
                "dask": "2021.01.0",
                "distributed": "2021.01.0",
                "msgpack": "1.0.0",
                "cloudpickle": "1.6.0",
                "tornado": "6.1",
                "toolz": "0.11.1",
                "numpy": "1.18.1",
                "lz4": "3.1.1",
                "blosc": "1.9.2"
            }
        }
    },
    "client": {
        "host": {
            "python": "3.8.6.final.0",
            "python-bits": 64,
            "OS": "Windows",
            "OS-release": "10",
            "machine": "AMD64",
            "processor": "Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel",
            "byteorder": "little",
            "LC_ALL": "None",
            "LANG": "None"
        },
        "packages": {
            "python": "3.8.6.final.0",
            "dask": "2021.01.0",
            "distributed": "2021.01.0",
            "msgpack": "1.0.0",
            "cloudpickle": "1.6.0",
            "tornado": "6.1",
            "toolz": "0.11.1",
            "numpy": "1.18.1",
            "lz4": "None",
            "blosc": "None"
        }
    }
}
```

I am suspecting the issue is with joblib, because if i run it without the line "with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):" the fit commands works fine.  Also, i tried a simple numpy array calcuation on dask worker and it works. So dask worker and connection from my client works good. i have tried with different versions of joblib. (0.16.0. 0.17.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1) and the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with different version of libraries running in worker and the client. I did a pip list from the worker and installed all the libraries with their specific versions on the client Docker file. Now it is working. am able to do the fit in dask workers